# Pandas check if row exist in another dataframe and append index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having one problem to iterate over my dataframe. The way I'm doing is taking a long time and I don't have that many rows (I have like 300k rows)

What am I trying to do?

1. Check if one DF (A) contains the value of two columns of the other DF (B). You can think of this as a multiple-key field
2. If True, get the index of `DF.B` and assign to one column of `DF.A`
3. If False, two steps:

a. append to `DF.B` the two columns not found

b. assign the new ID to `DF.A` (I couldn't do this one)

This is my code, where:

1. df is `DF.A` and df_id is `DF.B`:
2. SampleID and ParentID are the two columns I am interested to check if they exist in both dataframes
3. Real_ID is the column to which I want to assign the id of `DF.B` (df_id)

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #check if columns exist in the other dataframe
    real_id = df_id[(df_id['SampleID'] == row['SampleID']) & (df_id['ParentID'] == row['ParentID'])]
    
    if real_id.empty:
        #row does not exist, append to df_id
        df_id = df_id.append(row[['SampleID','ParentID']])
    else:
        #row exists, assign id of df_id to df
        row['Real_ID'] = real_id.index
```

EXAMPLE:

DF.A (df)

```
   Real_ID   SampleID   ParentID  Something AnotherThing
0             20          21          a          b      
1             10          11          a          b      
2             40          51          a          b
```

DF.B (df_id)

```
   SampleID   ParentID  
0    10          11         
1    20          21
```

**Result**:

```
   Real_ID   SampleID   ParentID  Something AnotherThing
0      1      10          11          a          b      
1      0      20          21          a          b      
2      2      40          51          a          b      


   SampleID   ParentID  
0    20          21         
1    10          11    
2    40          51
```

Again, this solution is very slow. I'm sure there is a better way to do this and that's why I'm asking here. Unfortunately this was what I got after some hours...

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some reproducible sample data sets and a desired output data set?

Comment: I added one example to show how the data is organized and what is the expected result. I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: could you please explain how did you get `Real_ID == 2` in the last row?

Comment: I got from the index of df_id (DF.B). I got the index where SampleID.A == SampleID.B && ParentID.A == ParentID.B. I changed the order so it makes it easier to read

Comment: there is no such index value in the original `DF.B` - that's why i'm asking...

Comment: I thought the row number could be used as the index. Sorry, I'm new to pandas. I can insert a column called `id` to be the index in `DF.B`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it this way:

Data (pay attention at the index in the `B` DF):

```
In [276]: cols = ['SampleID', 'ParentID']

In [277]: A
Out[277]:
   Real_ID  SampleID  ParentID Something AnotherThing
0      NaN        10        11         a            b
1      NaN        20        21         a            b
2      NaN        40        51         a            b

In [278]: B
Out[278]:
   SampleID  ParentID
3        10        11
5        20        21
```

**Solution:**

```
In [279]: merged = pd.merge(A[cols], B, on=cols, how='outer', indicator=True)

In [280]: merged
Out[280]:
   SampleID  ParentID     _merge
0        10        11       both
1        20        21       both
2        40        51  left_only


In [281]: B = pd.concat([B, merged.ix[merged._merge=='left_only', cols]])

In [282]: B
Out[282]:
   SampleID  ParentID
3        10        11
5        20        21
2        40        51

In [285]: A['Real_ID'] = pd.merge(A[cols], B.reset_index(), on=cols)['index']

In [286]: A
Out[286]:
   Real_ID  SampleID  ParentID Something AnotherThing
0        3        10        11         a            b
1        5        20        21         a            b
2        2        40        51         a            b
```

Comment: if I add `A['Real_ID'] = A[A[cols]==merged[cols]].index` will it be correct? It seems that it worked here, but I just wanted to make sure if the syntax is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use this merge function before without success. Your code runs super fast!

Comment: @MarcusRenno, glad i could help :)